# How to list all installed visual studio (CRT) C runtime in the desktop

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, crt

I am trying to run debug build application on another desktop. As usual I have faced CRT/dll hell.  Using sxstrace I obtained missing CRT runtime version (8.0.50727.6195) but it seems that the version of VisualStudio is the same as on my development desktop. 
I need to list all installed versions of CRT. is there any tool that can provide such information, so I can compare list from two hosts and got the right version of the Visual Studio?

Comment: Don't run the Debug build on another machine.  It will not have the debug version of the CRT available, msvcr80d.dll is only present on machines that have VS2005 installed.  The point of using C++ is to make code fast, there's no point left to it if you intentionally make it slow.  Only ever deploy the Release build.

Comment: You get these problems with release builds too, there are multiple installers for different versions of the same CRT runtime. I've had cases where I thought the target machine had the right runtime on but it simply doesn't work and installing "random" versions of the redistributable installer fixes it. (Obviously understanding it would be better). So I think there is a valid question here about how to tell what is actually installed on a target machine and how to tell what is missing.